# MAMP Pro - Apache won't start

Tags: php, apache, mamp, mamp-pro

I needed to change the PHP version (5.6.10) I was running for a project I was working on. I downloaded the PHP version I needed from the MAMP website, and put it in Applications/MAMP/bin/php. Restarted MAMP Pro, selected the new PHP version and tried to start the server, but got the "Apache wasn't able to start. Please check log for more information." error. Unfortunately the log is empty, so no help there.

If I revert to one of the original PHP versions (5.2.17 or 5.3.6) everything starts up correctly. I tried a bunch of different PHP versions and the only two that work are the ones that came installed with MAMP Pro originally.

Any thoughts as to what might be causing this issue?

I'm running Mavericks and have already renamed my envvars file to _envvars (when I first updated to Mavericks, as that was causing some issues as well).

Comment: Which PHP version you installed?

Comment: 5.3.6 and 5.2.17 both work, but 5.6.10 won't work.

Comment: What do you see when you use the Terminal to start MAMP? `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you download [MAMP](http://downloads3.mamp.info/MAMP-PRO/releases/3.4/php5.6.10.zip) with PHP 5.6.10 included?